# Save data in a variable - print null value

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```js
$(".open-modal").click(function () {
  console.log($(this).data('kdt'));
  var tableid = $(this).data('kdt');
  console.log(tableid)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="open-modal" data-kdt="user1">Click here</a>
```

First console.log print de value data correctly.
When I tried to save it in variable tableid, tableid is null...

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you share more code ?

Comment: Would you show some HTML?

Comment: Ok, I just edited it

Comment: @user3461461 I have just edited your code into a snippet, and as you can see it is working as expected...

Comment: Yes this works as expected... Was there perhaps some mistake in your code before copying it here?

Comment: It works, what's wrong?